# React +TypeScript - component that renders a dynamic element issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I feel like I'm pretty close but I can't take my compiler screaming at me anymore!

The problem seems to be arising with passing the ref, when `div` is in the `as` union.

When `div` is removed as a possible element to render, all my errors disappear:

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-cherry-udfg3

```
typescript


export interface BoxProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  /** The element to render */
  as: 'div' | 'section' | 'article' | 'aside' | 'header' | 'footer'
  /** The children to display */
  children?: React.ReactNode
  /** The ref to forward  */
  forwardRef?: React.RefObject<HTMLElement>
}

export function Box({ children, className, style, as: As, forwardRef, ...htmlProps }: BoxProps) {
  return (
    <As style={{ ...style }} className={cn('Box', className)} ref={forwardRef} {...htmlProps}>
      {children}
    </As>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `HTMLDivElement` extends `HTMLElement`, you could simply use

```
forwardRef?: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
```

to get rid of the compiler screams.

However, this solution looks a bit odd since `as` is not supposed to be exclusively a `div` element.

To make code clearer, you could use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) to combine `HTMLElement` with `HTMLDivElement`

```
forwardRef?: React.RefObject<HTMLElement & HTMLDivElement>
```

Comment: This makes sense! I wonder if there is anyway the above code could be rewritten to allow the user of the component to pass their own generic into both HTMLAttributes and RefObject?

Comment: Not sure about what you mean ?

Comment: For example if i were to add 'button' to the as union ts would hate me, i wonder if there is a way you might be able to pass the element type in: something like: 

<Box<HTMLButtonElement> as='button'>stuff</Box>

Comment: I see, not sure about this one for a React component ^^